# Why do kernel oopses taint and prohibit reporting with ABRT?

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, abrt

I freshly installed Fedora 28 on a laptop. On boot, I get a kernel oops I would very much like to report. However, ABRT recognizes the kernel as tainted with flags `GW` and thus refuses to report it. If I take a look at the [abrt documentation](http://abrt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-is-tainted-kernel-and-why-is-my-kernel-tainted), it is written that `W` means "a warning has previously been issued by the kernel." whereas `G` tells me that only GPL-compatible modules are loaded (as expected, I did not install any kernel modules myself).

But what exactly does this mean? Has the warning been issued by the kernel to bugzilla? This message really doesn't help me understanding why a freshly installed Linux leaves me with an error I am unable to report ...

`cat /proc/sys/kernel/tainted` also just gives the value 512, i. e. there is only a kernel warning according to the [sysctl documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt).

So how can I find out what exactly happened and why am I not allowed to report it with ABRT?

**Edit**: According to [this comment from 2012](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=786280#c3) on the RedHat Bugzilla

> 'w' means a warning has already occurred. We only care about the first one, which abrt should have already filed.

Thus I looked to find anything in the tainted report to find out where, if at all, ABRT reported the "first one" and found [this report on FAF](http://retrace.fedoraproject.org/faf/reports/2147917/) -- however, the kernel is marked as "tainted" as well, so the report will probably not be considered for fixing and I still don't know, why.

Comment: Did you figure out how to report tainted oopses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem might be that `abrtd` starts up too late to catch an oops that has occurred at boot time. When the oops happens, it causes the W taint flag to be set, and when abrtd starts up, it sees the W flag and cannot figure out whether the oops it finds is the first one.

If there was another oops before the one abrtd can see, there might be no point reporting the visible one as it might be just a consequence of whatever caused the first oops. You may know there wasn't one, but abrtd cannot make that determination automatically.

So, you might have to report a boot-time oops manually, especially if it happens early in the boot process.

The kernel alone won't report anything to any bugzilla; the W taint flag only means that one or more oops messages has already been logged by the kernel.